# Recipe and Images 2sxc 14 - forfactor forCss

Tags: image, 2sxc, recipe

It may be so new its not ready yet but for the life of me even with the default Blog app installed the images do not read the JSON recipe default file for which CSS is loaded BS4, BS5, etc. It only loads largest image file.

I think i read somewhere that it may be a work in progress but uncertain if it should be working in v.14.

This is the simple part of the code rendering it and tried even a custom recipe and it won't work.

```
@Kit.Image.Picture(link.Field("Image"), settings: imgSettings, imgAlt: altText, factor: "6/12"  )
```

Comment: well upon stumbling onto the Features/Extensions - learned that some features in 2sxc require you to be a patreon to activate credits and turn on features, one of them being this. 

Would be helpful to document this and any other features in the docs that require registration or credits

Answer (score 0):

I believe the custom recipe is part of the problem.

Basically it's correct that some features are Patrons only, but that is only for CSS-Framework specific resizes and for automatic WebP. Multiple sizes should work by default all the time - if the root recipe is correct.

I suggest you try a new DNN install with the latest 2sxc and the default Content-App. You should see that it creates multiple sizes automatically.

From there, figure out what broke in your setup.

Good luck!

Comment: It worked when the feature was just enabled via your Patrons so not sure, but it seems if the setting is set off "not enabled" that it would not work and the only way to enable was the Patron way which is completely fine. Now that we found out about that, we do intend to support you and use some of those features. Much love of some of the newer things introduced in 13 and 14 and curious your plans on the Prefill that is a WIP right now as it might extend how we use the custom view identifier.

Comment: awesome - thanks for supporting us. What do you mean by the prefill which is WIP right now? can't put a finger on it...